# Video player for application that loads RTMP feed

Tags: c#, wpf, media-player, rtmp

I am looking to integrate a RTMP player into an application I am creating to play a local live RTMP feed.

Could anyone recommend any good players? I've been looking at [OSMF Strobe Media Playback](https://sourceforge.net/adobe/smp/wiki/Home/) but have not pulled the trigger yet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find [a C# RTMP implementation here](https://github.com/nelemans1971/rtmp-mediaplayer).

It is tested to work on Windows, iOS and Android. You do need [BASS](https://www.un4seen.com/bass.html) to output audio. Video is not supported but the base RTMP client code (NetStream) exposes an event which gives you the video data as they arrive from the server.